# Can I get the AMS-Latex AMSTHM package to count theorems two different ways?

Tags: amsmath, counters, amsart

The AMSTHM, and AMS latex in general, do a good job of counting theorems.  For example "number by section" or "number by sub sub section. To satisfy multiple authors I need to do both.  For example:   Theorem 4.2.1.5 in sub subsection counting might be Theorem 4.23 in by section counting. I would like to use sub sub section counting, but display both counts :  Theorem 4.2.1.5 (aka 4.23).  I know I will need to define a new counter, but how I can get it the correct values I do not see.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.  Thanks cabohah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your theorems in another environment, that changes the numbering, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{stheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newcounter{dctheorem}[subsubsection]
\counterwithin{dctheorem}{subsection}
\newenvironment{dctheorem}{%
  \ifnum \value{subsection}>0
    \stepcounter{dctheorem}%
    \ifnum \value{subsubsection}>0
      \renewcommand*{\thestheorem}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{dctheorem} (aka
        \thesection.\arabic{stheorem})}%
    \else
      \renewcommand*{\thestheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{dctheorem} (aka
        \thesection.\arabic{stheorem})}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \stheorem  
}{%
  \endstheorem
}

\begin{document}

\section{Referencing}

See the theorems \ref{th:section}, \ref{th:subsectionA}, \ref{th:subsectionB},
\ref{th:subsubsectionA}, and \ref{th:subsubsectionB}.

\section{Test Section}

\begin{dctheorem}\label{th:section}
  This is a test theorem at section level.
\end{dctheorem}

\subsection{Test Subsection}

\begin{dctheorem}\label{th:subsectionA}
  This is a test theorem at subsection level.
\end{dctheorem}

\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\begin{dctheorem}\label{th:subsubsectionA}
  This is a test theorem at subsubsection level.
\end{dctheorem}

\begin{dctheorem}\label{th:subsubsectionB}
  This is another test theorem at subsubsection level.
\end{dctheorem}

\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\begin{dctheorem}\label{th:subsectionB}
  This is a test theorem at subsection level.
\end{dctheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: adapted numbering of theorems]